# Send email to different user based on some pattern in Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

We can send email notification to a particular email address but I want to send email to different mailing address based on some pattern in logs.

For example say I have three users with email address

1. userOne@something.com  receives mail id log contains [userOneModule]
2. userTwo@something.com  receives mail id log contains [userTwoModule]
3. userThree@something.com  receives mail id log contains [userThreeModule

Logstash version used is 1.3.3
Any help if this is possible in logstash or any workaround to achieve something like  this.

This is my configuration, Although both 'Security' and 'Portal' matches but email is sent to only one.

When I keep only one kind of logs say Security Logs or Portal Logs it works but when I keep both the logs it only sends email to one of it.

```
output { 

if [module] == "Security"{
    email { 
   to => "userOne@somemail.com" 
   from => "dummy2161@somemail.com"
    match =>["%{message}","severity,ERROR"]
   subject => "Error Occured" 
   body => "%{message}" 
   via => "smtp" 
   options => { 
     starttls => "true" 
     smtpIporHost => "smtp.gmail.com" 
     port => "587" 
     userName => "dummy2161@somemail.com" 
    password => "*******"  
     authenticationType => "plain" 
   } 
 }
 }
 if [module] == "Portal"{
    email { 
   to => "userTwo@somemail.com" 
   from => "dummy2161@gmail.com"
    match =>["%{message}","severity,ERROR"]
   subject => "Error Occured" 
   body => "%{message}" 
   via => "smtp" 
   options => { 
     starttls => "true" 
     smtpIporHost => "smtp.gmail.com" 
     port => "587" 
     userName => "dummy2161@somemail 
    password => "*****"  
     authenticationType => "plain" 
   } 
 }
 }
```

}

Thanks

Comment: try to use regular expressions

Comment: My logs contain [module-name] but my question is how will i send email to different users. can we have a if condition saying if (moduleName='userOne') then send email address is userOne@something.com in logstashConfigFile

Comment: Use  grok filter match to the Module name , make sure that module name in the logfile

Answer (score 0):

You can either store the recipient email address in a field (using conditionals or grok filters to assign the value) and refer to that field in the email output's `to` parameter, or you can wrap multiple email outputs in conditionals.

Using a field for storing the address:

```
filter {
  # If the module name is the same as the recipient address's local part
  mutate {
    add_field => { "recipient" => "%{modulename}@example.com" }
  }

  # Otherwise you might have to use conditionals.
  if [modulename] == "something" {
    mutate {
      add_field => { "recipient" => "someuser@example.com" }
    }
  } else {
    mutate {
      add_field => { "recipient" => "otheruser@example.com" }
    }
  }
}

output {
  email {
    to => "%{recipient}"
    ...
  }
}
```

Wrapping outputs in conditionals:

```
output {
  if [modulename] == "something" {
    email {
      to => "someuser@example.com"
      ...
    }
  } else {
    email {
      to => "otheruser@example.com"
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Magnus, I tried your solution it works but email is getting sent to  one the user only even though both the pattern is matching. I have edited my question and added my config file. Kindly review once.